# HTML5: Is <output> or <div> better for server status?

Tags: html

I have a page that auto-saves itself to the server (on timer, if any changes happened).
I want to add a small indicator, which will show `Unsaved`, `Saved` or `Error`.

Is it semantically valid to use the `<output>` tag for that, or should I use `<div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, although the answer will be somewhat subjective. I'll try to give my conclusion and reasoning.

Let's start with what the the spec has to say about the `<output>` element:

> The output element represents the result of a calculation.

That's not a lot to go on, really. Suppose, however, that it had said:

> The output element represents the result of a running of a process.

Then it would be clear that your use case was covered by that definition. So the key question becomes: can "calculation" be interpreted as "running of a process". It seems to me that a reasonable person could take either side of that argument.

But the language of HTML elements in HTML5 has only around 107 words. In such a small space, there's no room for nuances of meaning and each word must cover a lot of usages. To do so, the semantics of each element needs to be interpreted as liberally as possible, rather than as narrowly as possible. In that context, to me, "running of a process" is *sufficently similar* to "calculation" that usage of the `<output>` element is appropriate for your use case.

The other question to bear in mind is "does the use of the element cause unwanted behaviour in HTML consumers such a user-agents and search engines?" If it did, then that would be clear reason not to use it. However, `<output>` seems to be a passive element which does not cause any likely unwanted behaviours.

So my conclusion is that using the `<output>` element would be appropriate for your use case.

Comment: This makes sense. It is unfortunate that cases such as this are subjective, as it kind of defeats the point of trying to build a clear specification. However I agree with your understanding based on the existing one.